# How to get only one symbol from a symbol package?

Tags: symbols, packages, incompatibility

I need to use the `\Writinghand` symbol from the package `marvosym.sty`. But, for some reason, loading this package raises an error:

> (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifsym/ifsym.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \Sun already defined.
>                  Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

So, here is my general question:
**Is there a general procedure to follow when one wants to include only one symbol from a « symbol package » (a package that creates many new symbols)?**

Comment: Perhaps the package `bbding` and the command `\HandPencilLeft` represent a quick workaround?

Comment: see [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/579)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is no general procedure. One has to look into the package code and some knowledge of the terminal can be helpful; but one can always open the package file with an editor.

Let's see for `\WritingHand` that the Comprehensive List tells you it is from `marvosym.sty`.

First of all, we need to identify how the font is known to LaTeX. In these cases, rather than opening the file in an editor, I use `less`:

```
less $(kpsewhich marvosym.sty)
```

because `kpsewhich` is the utility that's used internally by the TeX programs to find a file. The first lines in the file are

```
\ProvidesPackage{marvosym}
  [2011/07/20 v2.2 Martin Vogel's Symbols font definitions]
\newcommand{\mvs}{\fontfamily{mvs}\fontencoding{U}%
\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
```

Good. We know how to load the font. The code is not the best possible, because

```
\newcommand{\mvs}{\usefont{U}{mvs}{m}{n}}
```

would be a cleaner call, although they're equivalent. The encoding `U` is “unspecified“ or “unknown”, which means that LaTeX won't try any of its tricks to adapt commands to the current encoding. It is a standard encoding, so there's no need to declare it beforehand. Any time we need a glyph from the font, we can say

```
\usefont{U}{mvs}{m}{n}
```

in a group. Now we look for `\WritingHand` and we find it on line 80:

```
\newcommand\WritingHand{\mvchr{98}}     \let\Writinghand\WritingHand
```

the second part is just an alias. What's `\mvchr`? It's on line 5

```
\newcommand{\mvchr}[1]{{\mvs\char#1}}
```

but it's again poor LaTeX programming, because `\symbol{#1}` would be better.

So we have all the necessary bits in order to accomplish our task:

```
\newcommand{\WritingHand}{{\usefont{U}{mvs}{m}{n}\symbol{98}}}
```

will work without loading any package. If you plan to use `\WritingHand` in moving arguments (sectional titles or captions, for instance), it may be better to use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`, otherwise in the `.aux` file you would find

```
{\fontencoding  {#1}\fontfamily  {#2}\fontseries  {#3}\fontshape  {#4}\selectfont  \ignorespaces \char 98\relax }
```

instead of a simple `\WritingHand`. Not much of a problem, but possibly annoying.

Suppose instead you want to use the glyph

[image]

that is available in the STIX font package. Looking at the documentation, we find it at position octal 204 (decimal 132) in the font `stix-extra1` (font table on page 43).

As before, we look in `stix.sty`, but we don't find `extra` inside it. Turn back to the documentation: on page 2 we find indeed

> There are also three fonts containing extra miscellaneous symbols, `stix-extra1`, `stix-extra2` and `stix-extra3`, provided as TFM and PFB files without support from the macro package.

This seems a problem, but indeed it isn't. We can proceed almost as before, just adding the necessary infrastructure

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{stixextrai}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stixextrai}{m}{n}
 { <-> stix-extra1 }{}

\newcommand{\WolframSym}{{\usefont{U}{stixextrai}{m}{n}\symbol{132}}}
```

The same caveat as before for `\DeclareRobustCommand` applies. The family name `stixextrai` is arbitrary. Example document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{stixextrai}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stixextrai}{m}{n}
 { <-> stix-extra1 }{}

\newcommand{\WolframSym}{{\usefont{U}{stixextrai}{m}{n}\symbol{132}}}

\begin{document}
\WolframSym
\end{document}
```

which is how I produced the image above.

Comment: See also [How to import a few symbols from `fdsymbol`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499803/) for another case.

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Writinghand{{\fontfamily{mvs}\fontencoding{U}\selectfont\char98}}
\begin{document}
\Writinghand 
\Huge \Writinghand
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a text symbol, the `\usefont` command will do, provided you know the characteristics of the font (encoding, family name, &c.) and  slot number of the symbols yoy want tu use. For you case there seems to be a name conflict between the `ifsym` and `marvosym` packages (there's also one with `mathabx`, cf. `The Comprehensive LaTeX  Symbol list`, p.101).  So you use a new command name in this way:

```
\newcommand\mySun{\usefont{U}{mvs}{m}{n}\char192}
```

Or if you want to keep the command names, you can overwrite the `\Sun` command from `ifsym` writing these lines in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[weather]{ifsym} 
\renewcommand\Sun{\usefont{U}{mvs}{m}{n}\char192}}%
```

Answer (score 0):

In `unicode-math`, there is: the `[range=...]` option of `\setmathfont`.  This lets you mix and match any math symbols in Unicode from any OpenType font to your heart’s content.