# Get only lambda from stix Package

Tags: symbols, stix

I am trying to use the (lowercase) lambda from the `stix` package without using the rest of `stix`. There is this question: [How to get only one symbol from a symbol package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174814/how-to-get-only-one-symbol-from-a-symbol-package/174822#174822). But I do not know how to get lower case lambda.

The code `\renewcommand{\lambda}{{\usefont{U}{stixextrai}{m}{n}\symbol{3}}}` gives capital lambda, and there is a list of codes here: http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/fonts/stix/doc/stix.pdf. However, I cannot seem to find the right number for the symbol I want.

Does anyone know the number/have a list of the numbers for symbols? Thanks in advance.