# \hat too small, \widehat too wide with Kepler font

Tags: symbols

I use the Kepler font in my document. It's a very good font for math but it has an issue typesetting the \hat and \widehat commands: the \hat command produces a very small hat and \widehat produces a hat that is too wide.

Is there a way to adjust the \hat and \widehat size?

Here's my MWE. The attached image displays the output.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsxtra}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
Kepler fonts

$\sigma, \hat{\sigma}, \widehat{\sigma}$

$\varepsilon, \hat{\varepsilon}, \widehat{\varepsilon}$

$a, \hat{a}, \widehat{a}$
\end{document}
```

[image: kpfonts hats]

Comment: Sorry, there is no image. Just run the MWE to see the results

Comment: Why are you including `stix2` before `kpfonts`? More to the point, why are you including `amssymb` after? That seems like it would, at best, have no effect, and at worst mess things up.

Comment: Stix2 is commented out

Comment: I cleaned up the code a bit and added a picture. Please check that I did not do a mistake.

Comment: This seems like a font issue to me. The hat doesn't look to narrow, it just is in the wrong place. You could try contacting the package maintainer to see if they will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Just slightly modifying my answer at [Really wide hat symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol/101136#101136), `\reallywidehat` will adjust to the width of the argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsxtra}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
\savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
  \scaleto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern.1pt\mathchar"0362\kern.1pt}%
    {\rule{0ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED CIRCUMFLEX
  }{\textheight}% 
}{2.4ex}}%
\stackon[-8.5pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}

\begin{document}
Kepler fonts

$\sigma, \hat{\sigma}, \widehat{\sigma}, 
\reallywidehat{\sigma}, \reallywidehat{\sigma\sigma\sigma}$

$\varepsilon, \hat{\varepsilon}, \widehat{\varepsilon}, 
\reallywidehat{\varepsilon}, 
\reallywidehat{\varepsilon\varepsilon\varepsilon}$

$a, \hat{a}, \widehat{a}, 
\reallywidehat{a}, \reallywidehat{aaa}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution! While you’re editing the MWE, you might remove `textcomp` (now part of the kernel) and `amssymb` (which `kpfonts` loads automatically). Although both are harmless, just unnecessary on a recent distro..

Comment: To Everybody: These are really great solutions and comments! I greatly appreciate  your taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can use the OTF version of the Kepler fonts, which you might prefer here.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
Kepler fonts

$\sigma, \hat{\sigma}, \widehat{\sigma}$

$\varepsilon, \hat{\varepsilon}, \widehat{\varepsilon}$

$a, \hat{a}, \widehat{abcd}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Kepler Fonts sample]

If you need to replace symbols from a different OpenType font, there is a standard syntax for that in `unicode-math`, e.g.:

```
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[Scale = MatchLowercase, range={\hat, \widehat}]
```

It is possible [to get only one accent from a math symbol package in legacy 8-bit LaTeX.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174814/how-to-get-only-one-symbol-from-a-symbol-package) Every 8-bit package is different, though.  There is no standard way to do it.