# \reallywidehat for use with unicode engines

Tags: math-mode

Since I would like a `\widehat` that is wider than `\hat` for a single letter, I searched and found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641778). However, when I was trying to compile with LuaLaTeX, I got the following result:

[image]

Is there some way to fix this?

---

Below is a MWE.

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
\savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
  \scaleto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern.1pt\mathchar"0362\kern.1pt}%
    {\rule{0ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED CIRCUMFLEX
  }{\textheight}%
}{2.4ex}}%
\stackon[-8.5pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}

\begin{document}
Kepler fonts

$\sigma, \hat{\sigma}, \widehat{\sigma}, 
\reallywidehat{\sigma}, \reallywidehat{\sigma\sigma\sigma}$

$\varepsilon, \hat{\varepsilon}, \widehat{\varepsilon}, 
\reallywidehat{\varepsilon}, 
\reallywidehat{\varepsilon\varepsilon\varepsilon}$

$a, \hat{a}, \widehat{a}, 
\reallywidehat{a}, \reallywidehat{aaa}$

$c, \hat{c}, \widehat{c}, 
\reallywidehat{c}, \reallywidehat{ccc}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Character 62 is a b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add

```
\fontname\textfont3
```

at the end, you'll see that the font is `KpMath-Regular.otf`, where the slot `U+0062` is occupied with a “b” and this explains what you get.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
  \sbox8{\ensuremath{#1}}%
  \savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
    \scaleto{%
      \scalerel*[0.08\wd8]{\kern.1pt{\hat{}}\kern.1pt}%
      {\rule{0ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED CIRCUMFLEX
    }{\textheight}%
  }{1.2ex}}%
  \stackon[-0.7ex]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}

\begin{document}
Kepler fonts

$\reallywidehat{\sigma\sigma\sigma\sigma\sigma\sigma\sigma\sigma\sigma\sigma}$

$\reallywidehat{\sigma\sigma\sigma}$

\end{document}
```

This needs fixes, but I leave to you the task, because I don't think that the result is worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you for this! Actually the problem for me is that the `\widehat` in the current version of `kpfonts` for single letters `c`, `e`, etc. seems too tight, and I have already sent an email to Herbert Voß (who seems to be the current maintainer of `kpfonts`) asking if this can be fixed (I remember in an earlier version there doesn't seem to be such a problem).