# Importing two symbols from stix2

Tags: symbols, intersections, stix2

I want to import two math symbols from stix2 package: `\rdiagovfdiag` and `\fdiagovrdiag` which look like this:

[image]

I want to do this, because adding the whole package changes style of my article which I don't like. I've seen in different posts (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174814/how-to-get-only-one-symbol-from-a-symbol-package)) that it is possible, but I don't know how to modify these examples in my situation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: In case my answer below does not solve your problem (i.e., the style of your article is still affected), you need to be a bit more specific: Provide a small document where one can observe the style change.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea is to make a copy of `stix2.sty`, search for the lines that define the two symbols, delete everything after these lines, and then going backwards to retain only those lines that are needed for defining the symbols.

Save the following lines in a file `mystix2.sty`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mystix2}[2023/11/10 pick X symbols from stix2.sty]
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows2}       {LS1}{stix2sf}   {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{arrows2}     {bold}{LS1}{stix2sf}   {b}{it}
\def\stix@undefine#1{%
    \if\relax\noexpand#1\let#1=\@undefined\fi}
\def\stix@MathSymbol#1#2#3#4{%
    \stix@undefine#1%
    \DeclareMathSymbol{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\stix@MathSymbol{\rdiagovfdiag}{\mathord}{arrows2}{"C4}
\stix@MathSymbol{\fdiagovrdiag}{\mathord}{arrows2}{"C5}
\endinput
```

Use it like in the following sample document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mystix2}
\begin{document}
$\rdiagovfdiag$ $\fdiagovrdiag$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need no package, actually.

The idea is to look how the commands are defined in `stix2.sty` and you find

```
\stix@MathSymbol{\rdiagovfdiag}{\mathord}{arrows2}{"C4}
\stix@MathSymbol{\fdiagovrdiag}{\mathord}{arrows2}{"C5}
```

OK, now we want to see what `arrow2` points to:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows2}       {LS1}{stix2sf}   {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{arrows2}     {bold}{LS1}{stix2sf}   {b}{it}
```

We have to look for `LS1`, which is a nonstandard encoding:

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
```

OK, we have all the ingredients. I add a prefix just to be sure that nothing gets clobbered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{STIX2arrows2}{LS1}{stix2sf}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{STIX2arrows2}{bold}{LS1}{stix2sf}{b}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\rdiagovfdiag}{\mathord}{STIX2arrows2}{"C4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\fdiagovrdiag}{\mathord}{STIX2arrows2}{"C5}

\begin{document}

$A\rdiagovfdiag\fdiagovrdiag B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't need the bold version, you can even avoid wasting a math group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rdiagovfdiag}{}{\text{\usefont{LS1}{stix2sf}{m}{it}\symbol{"C4}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fdiagovrdiag}{}{\text{\usefont{LS1}{stix2sf}{m}{it}\symbol{"C5}}}

\begin{document}

$A\rdiagovfdiag\fdiagovrdiag B$

\end{document}
```